# SonarQube email notification format changed after upgrade from 6.4 -> 6.7.2

Tags: sonarqube

We upgraded SonarQube from 6.4 to 6.7.2 and noticed after the upgrade the email notification format changed.

Version 6.4 included the break down of issues based on Severity:

Severity
Blocker: 0    Critical: 0    Major: 1    Minor: 5    Info: 4

Version 6.7.2 appears to now include a Type:

Type
Bug: 0    Vulnerability: 0    Code Smell: 15

Is there a way to configure the notification to include the Severity like we had in version 6.4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I heard from Sonarsource, The email format is not configurable.